# How to set Sympy preview output color?

Tags: python, latex, sympy

Sympy has a function `preview`. For example:

```
sympy.preview(formula, output='pdf', viewer='file', filename='temp.pdf')
```

But the output image is always black. Is it possible to set the output colour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dvioptions` argument

```py
sympy.preview(formula, output='pdf', viewer='file', filename='temp.pdf', dvioptions=["-fg", "Blue"])
```